# The selected team "A" is different from the team "B" originally used to build this item

Tags: xcode8

I developed an app with using my personal Apple developer account at the beginning and now I'm trying to archive/export it to "Save for Enterprise Deployment" using a Apple Enterprise developer account.  I understand the problem of creating the app under my personal Apple developer account and export using a Apple Enterprise developer account but I just don't know how to correct it.  I have talked with Apple several times but no luck.  Can someone out there please help me? xCode 8.3.3

[image]